# TYPO3 6.2 : "Desired storage is not in the list of available storages"

Tags: typo3, fal

After recreation of "File storage" objects, the Front End doesn't work anymore, *"online"* link points me [here](http://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1314085990).

In BE "fileadmin" folder is browserable, we could read/download files.

Anyone experienced such problem ?

[image: FE eror]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by Hubertus Golf helped me : https://forge.typo3.org/issues/62489

**problem:**

if you have files in table sys_file with a storage, that does'nt exist, TYPO3 throws an error.

**solution**

change field uid in sys_file_storage or field storage in sys_file.

Comment: Be aware of entries in sys_file_processedfile, too.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when trying to edit an FAL storage whose driver is not available/loaded.

This may happen by installing an extension that provides a storage adapter driver, then adding an storage with that driver, deactivating the extension and trying to edit that storage again.

We already opened a bug report 5 months ago: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/59017

Comment: Thx for the idea. Din't used any additional extensions to extend FAL. I've just installed empty TYPO3 with Introduction package, played a little bit with File Storage objects trying to get it work, and now there is such strange error.